# Can i set a font family inside <li> tag?

Tags: css, tags, html-lists, font-family

I'm guessing not because I've been trying it with examples and nothing works...

I'm curious why not? And how can I set this?

Thanks

Comment: not in CSS as Pekka below says...now what should i do...i dont need to change the style...but seems i need to put smthing like a <p> or <a> 
:/

Comment: Why would you ever want to use something other than CSS to change fonts?

Comment: i dont say that...i say i cant change li font family in the css file...how im gonna do it ?

Comment: If you're going to ask a question that shows little or not effort, at least mark the answer that did exhibit effort as the correct one (especially when it's correct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can. Just as for any other HTML element.

```
ul li { font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif }
```

Note that if the `li` contains other elements, and those elements have their own font-family settings, the value may get overridden. In that case, you'll have to specifically target the elements inside the li, e.g. for links:

```
ul li a { font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif }
```

Comment: hmm..maybe i ask it wrong...im doing it in a css file...
 
li {
  color:yellow;
  font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;
}

is it ok ?